# Autohotkey Shift Up is not working

Tags: macros, autohotkey

```
numpad8::
Send, {Shift down}
Send, {w down}
sleep, 100
Send, {Shift down}
Send, {w down}
return

numpad5::
Send, {Shift up}
sleep, 100
Send, {Shift up}
sleep, 100
Send, q
return
```

no matter what I try no matter how many times I press 5 on the numberpad it will not release the shift key. the strange thing is once I press 8 on the numberpad 5 will stop from typing out q...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed down, Numpad numbers behave otherwise (try it out manually yourself).

See https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm @ "Numpad5" to find out the key name of Numpad5, when Shift is pressed down: It's `NumpadClear`.

So I guess the easiest way to fix this is making both `numpad5` and `numpadclear` trigger the action:

```
numpad8::
Send, {Shift down}
Send, {w down}
sleep, 100
Send, {Shift down}
Send, {w down}
return

numpad5::
numpadclear::
Send, {Shift up}
sleep, 100
Send, {Shift up}
sleep, 100
Send, q
return
```

Comment: I can't believe I never realized this! Thank you so much this simple answer has been a great help.